# Calling flush() inside a model event causing a crash

Tags: shopware

I am trying to update an attribute inside a model event subscriber, but the code is causing a crash on Shopware v5.4.6

I have followed code instruction from the developer documentation and the forum

```php
class ModelSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate,
        ];
    }
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $modelManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $order        = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        if ( ! ($order instanceof Order)) {
            return;
        }

        if (
            ! $eventArgs->hasChangedField('paymentStatus') &&
            ! $eventArgs->hasChangedField('orderStatus')
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $order->getAttribute()->setNsupdate(1);

        $modelManager->persist($order);
        $modelManager->flush();//crash here

    }
}
```

The attribute "nsupdate" is already created and its type is a string.

I am only getting the error "0 - communication failure"

Please, what is wrong with my code?

**An update:**
I have tried

```php
        $modelManager->persist($order);
        $modelManager->flush($order);
```

and

```php
        $orderAttribute = $order->getAttribute();
        $orderAttribute->setNsupdate(1);
        $modelManager->persist($orderAttribute);
        $modelManager->flush($orderAttribute);//crash here
```

with the same crashing result.

Comment: Try to do it this way: $modelManager->flush($order)

Comment: @AlexeyPalamar, I have updated my question to answer you.

Comment: The problem you're having here is that by the time the preUpdate listener is executed, Doctrine already calculated the unit of work for the flush-operation. Modifying objects that are part of this UOW works fine, like modifying the Order, but adding new Objects to the UOW does not.
Calling flush from within your event listener executes the event listener again, causing an infinite recursion until your stack overflows. Your best options would be modifying the attribute natively with SQL, or modifying your attribute in a postUpdate listener. Calling flush from there won't cause an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the event you use.

The flush before the update is not necessary.

Comment: I have used Events::preUpdate, the database is not getting updated for some reason, I have ended up inserting/updating the attributes to the database directly as a temporary workaround